# Why is $R(x)$ not Archimedean?

Tags: real-analysis

Going through Pugh and came across this, where $R(x)$ is rational functions with real coefficients.
Is $R(x)$ Archimedean? That is, given $R ∈ R(x)$, does there exist a natural number $n ∈ R(x)$ such that $R < n$ ?
**Note:** A number $n$ is the rational function whose numerator is the constant polynomial $p(x) = n$, a polynomial of degree zero, and whose denominator is the constant polynomial $q(x) = 1$.

The answer is “no.” **Take $R(x) = x/1$. The numerator is $x$ and the denominator is $1$. Clearly we have $n < x$,** not the opposite, so $R(x)$ fails to be Archimedean.

What is going on here? Especially the bolded part. Why is $n < x$ ?

Comment: How do you order rational functions? What is the metric?

Comment: For "Archimedean" to have any meaning, you have to first define an order on $\mathbb{R}(x)$.  How does Pugh define that order?

Comment: He starts with making cuts in Q. I think he defines order by proving the set R(real numbers) is complete in the sense that it satisfies the least upper bound property

Comment: @AustralianSuper This is the order on $\mathbb{R}$, not on $\mathbb{R}(X)$.

Comment: "The order relation on R(x) is also easy to define. If R(x) > 0 for all sufficiently large x then we say that R is positive in R(x), and if R − S is positive then we write S < R. Since a nonzero rational function vanishes (has value zero)at only finitely many x∈R,we get trichotomy: either R=S, R<S, or S<R."

Comment: That's the order of R.  Not R (x).

Comment: Im getting more and more confused, he adds this straight after (To be rigorous, we need to prove that the values of a rational function do not change sign for x large enough.) The other order properties are equally easy to check, and R(x) is an ordered field.

Comment: There's your answer then.  x -n > 0 for sufficiently large x. So x > n.

Comment: Oh ok. Should i go on and delete this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R (x) $f (x) > g (x)$ if  $f (x)-g (x) $ is positive for sufficiently large x.

So when x is larger (in the real sense) then n then $x-n$ is positive so $x > n $.